# Countable union of Menger spaces.

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ has [Menger's property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_space) $\textsf{S}_{\mbox{fin}}(\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{O})$ if, for each sequence of open covers, $\mathcal{U}_1, \mathcal{U}_2, \cdots $, we can select finite sets $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2, \cdots $ whose union $\bigcup_{n}\mathcal{F}_n$ covers the space.

My question is if the Menger's property is preserved by countable unions, that is, if for each $n\in\omega$, $X_n$ is a Menger space, then $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}X_n$, with the disjoint union topology is a Menger space.

Thanks

Comment: Since not everyone  is familiar with Menger spaces, you should mention that $F_n\subset U_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*To kick it from the unanswered queue*)

[Taras Banakh](https://mathoverflow.net/users/61536/taras-banakh)'s comment on your [crossposted question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331018/countable-union-of-menger-spaces):

> The answer is well-known and is "yes": just divide the sequence of covers into infinitely many parvise disjoint sequences of covers and cover $n$-th set $X_n$ by the union of finite subfamilies from the corresponding subsequences of covers.